# How do I apply this model to my data (multiple regression?)

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

This is a results table reported in a paper I read where they are using several parameters to predict dry matter intake in cattle.

[image]

If this were a simple linear regression with the formula y = mx + c, I could take the slope and intercept, plug in my own values for x and generate a predicted y according to the model.

Can I do something similar using my data and the information in this table, or is there not enough information in this table for me to do so?

Comment: Re the title: you are not asking about "adding data to the model," but rather about *applying* the fitted model to your data.

Comment: thanks whuber and appologies for the inacuracy - title altered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having looked at some other papers using multiple regression methods, it would seem i can use the data above with my own values for X1, X2, X3 and X4.  e.g. for final line in the table, i would calculate as follows:

DM intake = 2.56 + (-0.0125*TA) + (-0.0348*PA) + (0.0081*DM) + (0.0112*D-value)

This gives me plausible values for DM intake so i assume i am using the data correclty.